# What are specific security threats to a Monero GUI?

Tags: security, monero-wallet-gui, hot-wallet

As the release of the official Monero GUI approaches, I would like to ask the best ways to secure our systems against possible theft.  Apart from keyloggers catching your mnemonic seed or password, I am currently unaware of any other attack vectors that might compromise a GUI wallet.

Is there anything else that may prove to be a threat to a GUI wallet (with possible variation depending on the user's OS), and what are the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible that certain APIs such as for the [Monero Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/monerocurrency) could be a possible security threat. Although any APIs that are added to the wallet will be believed to be safe by the developers that implement them, the safest practice would be to disable APIs that you will not be using. In the case of Twitter, its API will be [disabled](https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core/pull/12) by default.